# Generation of products of power

Tags: python, performance, primes

Given positive integers a,b,c and limit, I want to generate all products having the form
$$p^aq^br^c \leq limit$$ less than limit (where p,q,r are distinct primes). a,b and c are not necessary distinct.

I tried something like:

```
primes= [ 2,3,5,...] # primes up to 10**8
[ (p**a)*(q**b)*(r**c) for p in primes for q in primes for r in primes if (p**a)*(q**b)*(r**c) <= limit ]
```

But it is very slow because len(primes)(=5761455) is high.

Then I tried a very ugly code for printing values. 
It generates all values for p < q < r (p, q, r primes)

```
def generate3(a,b,c,limit):
    global primes
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 1
    i3 = 2
    while i1 < len(primes) and i2 < len(primes) and i3 < len(primes) and (primes[i1]**a)*(primes[i2]**b)*primes[i3]**c < limit:
        print(str(i1)+" "+str(i2)+str(i3))
        while i1 < len(primes) and i2 < len(primes) and i3 < len(primes) and (primes[i1]**a)*(primes[i2]**b)*primes[i3]**c< limit:
            while i1 < len(primes) and i2 < len(primes) and i3 < len(primes) and (primes[i1]**a)*(primes[i2]**b)*primes[i3]**c< limit:
                print(str(primes[i1])+" "+str(primes[i2])+" "+str(primes[i3])+" "+str((primes[i1]**a)*(primes[i2]**b)*(primes[i3]**c)))
                i3 = i3 + 1
            i2 = i2 +1
            i3 = i2 +1
        i1 = i1 + 1
        i2 = i1 + 1
        i3 = i2 + 1
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?
Is there a better method for generating these products of powers quickly?

Comment: Is the constraint `p < q < r ` a coincidence, or one of the do they just need to be distinct?

Comment: They just need to be distinct but the second example I gave only generates cases for which p < q < r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## global

there is no need to make `primes` a `global`. You only read from it, but don't assign to it, you can use it as is. It will be even faster if you make `primes` a local variable by passing it in as a parameter, so Python uses the  `LOAD_FAST` bytecode instead of `LOAD_GLOBAL`. Since `primes` is called, indexed and sliced a lot, this can make a difference.

## while condition

`i1 < len(primes) and i2 < len(primes) and i3 < len(primes) and ...`. Since `i1<i2<i3`, only `i3 < len(primes)` is needed. If you use `len(primes)` so often, it pays to make it a local variable.

## return, don't print

your method immediately prints the results. In general it is better to split the calculation and presentation, so to let the method `return` or `yield` the values, and another method do the presentation

## looping

I suggest you watch the talk [Loop like a Pro](https://archive.org/stream/pycon-2017-looping#mode/2up) by David Baumgold. It's recommended material for every python programmer.

Instead of looping over the indices, you can loop over the primes-list immediately.

For `p`, and the first index (`i`), you can loop over `enumerate(primes)`

Then you can use this index `i` to slice `primes` to only include the elements with an index larger than `p` and go on to `r`, so you arrive at the following, naive implementation:

```
def generate4_naive(a, b, c, limit):
    for i, p in enumerate(primes):
        for j, q in enumerate(primes[i+1:], i+1):
            for r in primes[j+1:]:
                product = p**a * q**b * r**c
                if product < limit:
                    yield p, q, r, product
```

If you include the early `break`s, you arrive at something like this:

```
def generate4(a, b, c, limit):
    for i, p in enumerate(primes):
        for j, q in enumerate(primes[i+1:], i+1):
            sub_product = p**a * q**b
            for r in primes[j+1:]:
                product = sub_product * r**c
                if product > limit:
                    break
                yield p, q, r, product
            if sub_product * primes[j+1]**c > limit:
                break
        if p ** a * primes[i+1] **b * primes[i+2] ** c > limit:
            return
```

then I also used `primes` as a local variable by changing the signature: `def generate4b(a, b, c, limit, primes):`

## Performance:

```
limit = 1_000_000
%timeit tuple(generate3(2,3,4, limit=limit))
```

> ```
> 16.6 µs ± 166 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit tuple(generate3b(2,3,4, limit=limit, primes=primes))
```

> ```
> 16.2 µs ± 138 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit tuple(generate4(2,3,4, limit=limit))
```

> ```
> 14.2 µs ± 643 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit tuple(generate4b(2,3,4, limit=limit, primes=primes))
```

> ```
> 7.72 ms ± 516 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit list(generate4_naive(2,3,4, 1_000)) # primes also only to 1000
```

> ```
> 940 ms ± 84.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
> ```